# what is the purpose of adding an extension for browser in selenium -like firebug?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to figure out the use of a firebug extension in Selenium WebDriver tests. How come it is helpful while testing ? Can any one share its use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, Selenium developers will either use Chrome developer tools, or enable the Firebug extension in their firefox profile for the reason of specificity.

Considering you find Selenium objects using different selector strategies, an extension like Firebug allow the Selenium developer to find unique things about that element, so they can use it in their scripts.

#### Here is an example

[image]

In this example, you can see the Chrome Developer tools (effectively the same thing as Firebug).  In there, a developer is able to find attributes that will uniquely identify that element, and then in succession, use the Firebug javascript console to utilize javascript libraries on the page (*either jQuery, or simply `document.querySelectorAll`) to make sure that the element is unique.

you can see in this example, that there are 2 `<a>`'s that are returned, therefore that element is not unique.  the developer would then look at the tree to figure out how to uniquely identify only that One `"Download"` button

Comment: sircapsalot, we can define FirefoxProfile object & for that profile we can add extensions - using addExtension() method. Why we need it during a test session. I know its default usage as a firefox plugin. But I need how it is help in code.

Comment: read the answer.  I answered that question.  to utilize it to find your elements you want manually.

Comment: @dinesh Firebug or Chrome Developer extensions usage is not limited in testing with selenium. But ppl prefer to quickly crawl page and check DOM elements attributes and then can use in test code.

Other cases where I prefer such Console tool to debug HTML. There will cases when you test cases might not be running correctly. You would like to run test inin debug Mode, so only way to inspect HTML is Firebug (for Firefox browser). Hope that clear ur doubt !!!

Comment: Thank you aberry. I have seen a video regarding - debugging. I got some knowledge out of it. Okay, What is the shortcut key for firebug to open in browser when selenium open a  new session. When I was passing firebug as an extension, it is been added perfectly to the new browser session.